# wordpress set cookie in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, http-headers, shortcode

I am writing a wordpress plugin where I have a shortcode. This shortcode generates and handles a form. When the form is submitted, a value is stored in a cookie with:

```
$result = setCookie('cookieName','cookieValue');
```

Result then returns false, meaning the cookie is not set. This is not suprisingly, since headers are already sent when the shortcode is executed. I am looking for a way to solve this problem.

I have found multiple similar questions here. Most answers were: set the cookie earlier, but that is not really an option for me.

The only thing i could think of was output buffering everything, but I am not sure what is the correct way to do this in wordpress (which hooks, how to keep things compatible with other plugins etc). I also wonder if there is a built-in solution, since it seems to me that I will not be the only one with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

well i just wrote an answer for another question,  i hope this could best define how and where to write a cookie which you want to use in a shortcode.

[need the right way to setcookie in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393404/need-the-right-way-to-setcookie-in-wordpress/45633981#45633981)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah WP's design doesn't allow for this.  If using an early action like 'init' is not suitable, the only other thing I can think of is doing an AJAX call, where it's fine to use setcookie in the callback for that, also javascript can set cookies directly.

If you absolutely need to calculate this in the shortcode's callback then perhaps you could store something in the $_SESSION first, or a hidden form, or data attribute, and put it into a cookie later (using 'init' action, or passing the value to javascript and using that to create the cookie)